# Where to locate the path to node.socket in order to set CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH env variable?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

I would like to check the sync progress of the cardano node from within a cardano-node-ogmios docker container that I installed. When I open the docker CLI and I run the command `cardano-cli query tip --mainnet` I get that $CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH environment variable is not defined. I've tried locating /db/node.socket path, but I cannot seem to find it. Any clue as to where it may be located?

Comment: Just a side note, you can run cardano-tip outside of container, no need to login to container. I use it something like that from the host: `docker exec -ti test-producer /usr/local/bin/cardano-cli query tip --testnet-magic 1097911063`

Answer (score 1):

After checking the Ogmios documentation again I finally found it in /ipc/node.socket. (Post can be deleted or remain in case for future reference)

Comment: Including the snippet of the documentation would improve your answer and remember you can mark your own answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

A note for other people, when starting your node the `--socket-path` option will contain the path to the socket.

CARDANO_NODE_SOCKET_PATH should match this value.

```
cardano-node run \
   --topology path/to/mainnet-topology.json \
   --database-path path/to/db \
   --socket-path path/to/db/node.socket \
   --host-addr x.x.x.x \
   --port 3001 \
   --config path/to/mainnet-config.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create db folder inside your cardano-node, and pointing your script to that folder, the node.socket will be created once after you node is sync 100%